# EAccess Violation when initializing char matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, char, c++builder

I have a basic c++ exercise. I need to pass some listed words to a char matrix but i have a problem initializing the matrix...

This is my code:

```
class Cahorcado
{
    public:
        //functions
        Cahorcado(void);
        private:
        char** palabra;
};        
Cahorcado::Cahorcado(void)
{
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        for(int i2=0;i2<255;i2++)
        {
            palabra[i2][i]=' '; //i'm getting the error over here
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the "EAccess Violation" error...
I **cant** use strings, must be char's or AnsiString's(c++ builder).
I don't know if im even declaring the char matrix good.
What i have in mind is something like this:

```
{'H','e','l','l','o', , 
 'W','o','r','l','d', , 
  , , , , , , 
  , , , , , , }
```

(just to make an idea)

http://pastebin.com/gBQvED5h <- Full code (**Spanish Warning**)

Comment: Hint: think of what your pointers are pointing to.

Comment: Unless you have a `palabra  =new char*[26];` and 26 `palabra[i]  =new char [255];`s or similar hiding out there you haven't allocated storage for your array.

Comment: It will no longer crash at that point if you change `char** palabra;` to `char palabra[255][26];`. However, it may still crash elsewhere in the code that you did not post.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gBQvED5h <- Full code (**Spanish Warning**)

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your class constructor you should have the following in order to allocate array storage,

```
palabra = new char*[rows];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    palabra[i] = new char[cols];
```

where `rows` and `cols` represent the number of rows, columns in the 2D array respectively.

Then in your destructor you would need,

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    delete[] palabra[i];
delete[] palabra;
```

in order to destroy the dynamically allocated memory and avoid a memory leak.

The above is pretty-obsolete C++ though and the better way to do this would be via STL containers which handle memory allocation and de-allocation internally. For example, you could use a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` object to store your character matrix, then your class would look something like:

```
class Cahorcado {
public:
    // create char matrix with each element initialised with ' '
    Cahorcado(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) 
        : palabra(rows, std::vector<char>(cols,' ')) {}

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> palabra;
};
```

Comment: Hum... The compiler throws "Body has already been defined for function 'Cahorcado::Cahorcado(unsigned int,unsigned int)' "

Comment: I suspect you tried to define `Cahorcado::Cahorcado(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)` in your cpp file and already had it defined in the class declaration when you copied the code above.

Comment: so... into the class declaration:  `Cahorcado(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) 
        : palabra(rows, std::vector<char>(cols,' ')) {}` the "{}" are wrong?